# Geocode Factory with Sobipro

Tags: geocode, sobipro

I installed joomla 2.5, and Geocode Factory 3 with Sobipro,I set any parameters and installed madules and pluggings but i cant see map in search page!

is there any body to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've already read this:

http://www.myjoom.com/documentation/geocode_factory_3/sobipro

Also, I'm sure when you say "search page" you mean in "SobiPro search view", right? That is, this does not work in Joomla's search :).

Finally, you mentioned you installed plugins, so most probably you installed this one, right?

http://www.myjoom.com/products/geocode-factory-3/103-sobipro-map-search

Please note that this is a paid plugin, so you should be able to get support from myJoom on this, which most probably will be way better that "generic support" here.

Also, you have the alternative of using SobiPro's native geomap field and module, which are also capable of displaying search results in a map. These are also subscriber only add-ons, but you'll get access to SobiPro support for them.